# how to pull data in new Firebase using java mobile?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I created A method that could be able to get the data in my firebase using the userId when I debugging it, it couldn't be able to go inside am wondering whats wrong with my code. This is my code:

```
 public static String GetUserRole(final String userId){
        Role = null;
        getUsersRef().child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String role = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return Role;
    }
```

is there any problem with this?

Comment: Do you mean that the **onDataChange** and **onCancelled** methods were not called at all?

Comment: when i debug on the top it wont go inside of getUsersRef().child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() this am wondering whats wrong with this

Comment: this is the firebase documentation and almost i followed it but didnt work : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

When implementing the **ValueEventListener**, the overridden methods are called when an event happens. this means that it isn't called and executed when the **GetUserRole** method is executed, but it is called separately, when the event happens (data received from Firebase). If you print a log you will see that the **onDataChange** method or the **onCancelled** method will be called (after **GetUserRole** run).

Try adding a Log print like this:

```
    getUsersRef().child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: try using **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** instead of **addValueEventListener**

Comment: yeah i did thats what I do in my posted